# socket.io net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm testing with socket.io and unity.

In my localhost (my pc) did walk perfectly but now I got all on my hosting to see how it works online and i have the following problem:

url app online: http://almightysystem.com.ar/UnityApps/UnityChatSocket.io/

I have this loop error:

```
GET http://almightysystem.com.ar:29011/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423454072758-3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var port = process.env.PORT || 29011;

var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(message){
        io.emit('chat message', message);
    });
});

http.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

client.js:

```
//SOCKET.IO
var socket = io.connect('http://almightysystem.com.ar:29011/');

socket.on('chat message', function(message){
    SendMessage ('ChatSystem', 'GetChatMessage', message);
    console.log("Mensaje recibido del Servidor hacia Unity: " + message);
});

function UnitySendMessage(message){
    socket.emit('chat message', message);
    console.log("Mensaje de Unity al Servidor: " + message);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is the `:29011` in this `'http://almightysystem.com.ar/UnityApps:29011'`?  If it's meant to be a port number, it is not in the right place.  It would go right after the domain.

Comment: Omg, you are right. Now works, but I have another problem GET http://almightysystem.com.ar:29011/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423453430420-0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer to this problem.

In your client code.

```js
// SOCKET.IO

var socket = io.connect('http://almightysystem.com.ar:29011/');

socket.on('chat message', function(message){
    SendMessage ('ChatSystem', 'GetChatMessage', message);
    console.log('Mensaje recibido del Servidor hacia Unity: ' + message);
});

function UnitySendMessage(message){
    socket.emit('chat message', message);
    console.log('Mensaje de Unity al Servidor: ' + message);
}
```

Remove the port number in the `connect` function.

```js
var socket = io.connect('http://almightysystem.com.ar:29011/');
```

Like this.

```js
var socket = io.connect('http://almightysystem.com.ar');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your client side `const socket = io("http://almightysystem.com.ar:29011/", { transports: ["websocket"] });` to specify you want to use websockets

Answer (score 0):

In your server code, you should use `server.listen(port, ...)` and not `app.listen(port, ...)` because `app.listen()` [creates a *new* http server](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/fea768dbccc036d883b03e38daebc38e5206031c/lib/application.js#L558) and attaches to that, which you do not want because you already have one (`server`).

Also, in your client code, you should use `io.connect('http://almightysystem.com.ar:29011/');` instead of `io.connect('http://almightysystem.com.ar/UnityApps:29011');` because the socket.io server won't know to listen on `/UnityApps` (because you're not passing a config object (with `path` set) to the [socket.io server constructor](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server(opts:object))), even after you've moved the `:29011` part to the right place.

Comment: Omg, you are right. Now works, but I have another problem GET http://almightysystem.com.ar:29011/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423453430420-0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it using

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

instead of

```
var socket = io.connect('http://almightysystem.com.ar:29011/');
```